# How do I change settings in QuickTime 10?

Tags: quicktime

I'm trying to follow these instructions on configuring QuickTime so I can use a browser-based web app that uses QuickTime as a plugin in FireFox: http://tones.wolfram.com/tsfaqs/osx/configurequicktime.html

I'm using QuickTime Player version 10.4 (833.1). The instructions I'm reading clearly indicate that QuickTime Player should have a Preferences option in its menu bar, as shown in this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTlAT.jpg]

However, my version of QuickTime Player does not seem to have any preferences whatsoever:

[image]

How do I change QuickTime settings using QuickTime Player 10.4?

Comment: Open the "QuickTime player 7", in your Utility folder.

Comment: I don't have QuickTime Player 7 in my Applications/Utilities folder.

Answer (score 1):

For that website you need the legacy version of QuickTime player. It is called `QuickTime player 7` and is located in your `/Applications/Utility` folder.

If it is not there get it from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL923?locale=en_US).